# Multiple File Upload using Reactive Form in angular

Tags: angular

I want to upload multiple files and want to display the preview of image files uploaded using reactive form

I tried using formArray, but it is not displaying the images.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();

  }
  initForm() {
    this.multiForm = this.fb.group({
      albumName: ['', Validators.required],
      multiImages: this.fb.array([this.createImage()])
    })
  }
  createImage() {
    const newImage = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
    (<FormArray>this.multiForm.get('multiImages')).push(newImage)
  }

  get multiImages() : FormArray {
    return this.multiForm.get('multiImages') as FormArray;
  }

onFileUpload(event:any) {
    this.urls = [];
    let selectedFiles =  event.target.files;
    console.log(selectedFiles);
    if(selectedFiles) {
      for(let file of selectedFiles) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.urls.push(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML File

```
<div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="js-upload uk-placeholder uk-text-center uk-width-1-2 uk-margin-left">
                <span uk-icon="icon: cloud-upload"></span>
                <span class="uk-text-middle">Attach binaries by dropping them here or</span>
                <div uk-form-custom>
                    <input type="file" (change)="onFileUpload($event)" name="multiImages" multiple>
                    <span class="uk-link"> selecting one</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
             <div class="uk-flex">
            <button class="uk-button uk-margin-large-left" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="multiImages.length">
            <div formArrayName="multiImages" *ngFor="let image of multiImages.controls; let i = index">
            <div [formGroupName] = "i">
            <img class="uk-flex uk-margin-large-left" [src]="image.controls.url.value" width="180" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Preview of multiple images should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere that you are actually pushing values to your `FormArray`, so you need to do that. You can do it at the same time as you push values to your `urls` array. Here I use the function you have `createImage()`:

```ts
reader.onload = (e: any) => {
  this.urls.push(e.target.result);
  this.createImage(e.target.result);
}
```

and `createImage()`:

```ts
createImage(img) {
  const newImage = new FormControl(img, Validators.required);
  (<FormArray>this.multiForm.get('multiImages')).push(newImage)
}
```

When building your form, you called `createImage`, removed that. After adding the image, in your template iterate your form array as you are and display image using `image.value`:

```html
<div  *ngFor="let image of multiImages.controls; let i = index">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <img [src]="image.value" width="180" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgn6bf?file=src/app/app.component.html)**